# What is wrong with my while loop?

Tags: java, while-loop

```
System.out.println("Enter a string: ");
String myString = userInput.nextLine();

while (myString != "done") {
        System.out.println(myString);
        System.out.println("Enter another string: ");
        myString = userInput.nextLine();

        }
```

My objective here is to print out all the strings that user inputs until the user types in the string "done". What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Classic: `!=` doesn't check string equality, but pointer equality.

Try

```
while (!myString.equals("done")) {
```